# Keras predictions on tf.data dataset doesn't stop

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.data.dataset

I have run into a problem with using a generator to do predictions for my model.
According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) if `steps = None` predict should run through the whole dataset.
But instead, it goes passed it and I starts again. I'm using `flow_from_dataframe` on an image dataset.

Should I fix the step size to `ceil(len(dataset) / batch_size)`?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well it's not a real solution, but fixing the stepsize to the length of the dataset did it.
I guess the docs have to be updated.